# Rotation matrix of a unit cell coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am doing a research project, and in the project I am doing a simulation for cubic unit cells (from materialproject) of different materials, the way it works is by loading a bunch of coordinates, the coordinates are given in zone axis $(0,0,1)$, but I also need them in $(0,1,1)$ and $(1,1,1)$, I was told to use a rotation matrix but I am not sure how to do that, I rotated the coordinates around $x$-axis by $45$ degrees using a matrix from Wikipedia which seems to be very close for $(0,1,1)$ because I have experiment results to compare with, not sure if it's the same, can anyone help or provide a rotation matrix? Here is an image to maybe help clarify
[image]

Comment: So materialproject gives you coordinates along $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$ and you want them in a different coordinate system? You need three independent vectors.

Comment: Materialsproject gives coordinates of unit cell as if it was oriented in (0,0,1) zone axis, I want to rotate all the given (x,y,z) vector coordinates to (0,1,1) and (1,1,1)

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the following notations:

- the materialsproject coordinates are given by a vertical vector $\begin{pmatrix}h\\k\\l\end{pmatrix}$
- the coordinates you want form a vertical vector $\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\c_3\end{pmatrix}$
- coordinate $c_i$ is along a vector $w_i$, $i=1,2,3$, where the components of $w_i$ are $(w_{i,h}, w_{i,j}, w_{i,k})$. The vectors $w_i$ are independent.

Then$$\begin{pmatrix}h\\k\\l\end{pmatrix}=W\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\c_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}w_{1,h}&w_{2,h}&w_{3,h}\\w_{1,k}&w_{2,k}&w_{3,k}\\w_{1,l}&w_{2,l}&w_{3,l}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\c_3\end{pmatrix}$$
If you want to get the new coordinates, just multiply the above equation on the left by $W^{-1}$:
$$W^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}h\\k\\l\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\c_3\end{pmatrix}$$